# How to extend ServiceStack's RequestLogsFeature in order to log every request?

Tags: servicestack

How extend **ServiceStack's** **RequestLogsFeature** in order to save every single log (with ServiceStack's log manager)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Request Logs Feature to use your custom [IRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequestLogger.cs) by specifying it when registering the plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature { 
    RequestLogger = new MyCustomRequestLogger(),
});
```

If no Request Logger is specified it will use the [InMemoryRollingRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs) by default.